# How to load/render vw value or if window width <= 1920 and how we can load/render px value if window with > 1921. and how we can convert that in scss

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

Hello StackOverFlow Community
Hope all are fine there

I am currently stuck in the issue where i need to convert all the vw properties in css to px when window width is > 1921.
if view viewport width is < 1921 then all value remain same in vw format

i am converting vw properties using scss function

here is snippet of that function

```
@function stripUnit($value) {
    @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
}
@function vw($pxValue) {
    @return #{stripUnit($pxValue) / stripUnit($html-font-size)}vw;
}
```

Using in scss following below

```
.down-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: vw(42px);
  bottom: vw(220px);
  width: vw(100px);
  height: vw(100px);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: $white;
  z-index: 9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5);
}
```

Need to convert above snippet when window viewport > 1921px

```
.down-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 42px;
  bottom: 220px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: $white;
  z-index: 9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `mixin` like the code below:

```
$html-font-size: 16;
$white: #FFF;

@mixin vwChange {
  @media (max-width: 1921px) {
    right: vw(42px);
    bottom: vw(220px);
    width: vw(100px);
    height: vw(100px);
  }
  right: 42px;
  bottom: 220px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


@function stripUnit($value) {
  @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
}

@function vw($pxValue) {
    @return #{stripUnit($pxValue) / stripUnit($html-font-size)}vw;
}

.down-arrow {
  @include vwChange;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: $white;
  z-index: 9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5);
}
```

I set some arbitrary values to `$html-font-size` and so on just to test the code.

Comment: I have more 10000+ line of scss code
if we do like that it will time consuming

Comment: You don't need to change everything. Just change parts that use ```vw()``` function. When you want to code a responsive website, you must rewrite some necessary codes inside **@media** rules. That is the basic principle of CSS.